# How to check if current user id is not equal to database entry?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a friends page which pulls rows from a database, I only want to display the current users friends but it only returns the current user from the query.

Database Table:

[image]

Current Code:

```
function getFriends($user_id, $sqli_con) {
    $user_id = mysqli_escape_string($sqli_con, strip_tags($user_id));

    $results = $sqli_con->query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE receiver_id = '$user_id' AND accepted = '1' OR sender_id = '$user_id' AND accepted = '1'");

    if($results->num_rows > 0) {

        while($row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            if($row['receiver_id'] === $user_id || $row['sender_id'] === $user_id) {

            } else {
                $username_stmt = $sqli_con->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM members WHERE id = {$row['receiver_id']} OR id = {$row['sender_id']}");
                $username_stmt->execute();
                $username_stmt->store_result();
                $username_stmt->bind_result($id, $username);
                $username_stmt->fetch();
                $username_stmt->close();
                $results->free();

                return "

                    <div id='friend'>
                        <a href='profile.php?id=".$id."'><img src='". getProfileImagePath($id, $sqli_con) . "' /></a>
                        <a href='profile.php?id=".$id."'>". $username . "</a>
                    </div>

                ";
            }

        }

    } else {
        $results->free();
        return "You don't have any friends yet! :( Why not search for some?";
    }
}
```

Currently no results are returned but if I take out the user id check it only returns the current user.

EDIT:
I got it working, solution:

```
function getFriends($user_id, $sqli_con) {
    $user_id = mysqli_escape_string($sqli_con, strip_tags($user_id));

    $results = $sqli_con->query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (receiver_id = '$user_id' OR sender_id = '$user_id') AND accepted = '1'");

    if($results->num_rows > 0) {

        while($row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            if($row['sender_id'] !== $user_id) {
                $username_stmt = $sqli_con->prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE id = {$row['sender_id']}");
                $username_stmt->execute();
                $username_stmt->store_result();
                $username_stmt->bind_result($username);
                $username_stmt->fetch();
                $username_stmt->close();

                echo "

                    <div id='friend'>
                        <a href='profile.php?id=".$row['sender_id']."'><img src='". getProfileImagePath($row['sender_id'], $sqli_con) . "' /></a>
                        <a href='profile.php?id=".$row['sender_id']."'>". $username . "</a>
                    </div>

                ";
            }
            if($row['receiver_id'] !== $user_id) {
                $username_stmt = $sqli_con->prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE id = {$row['receiver_id']}");
                $username_stmt->execute();
                $username_stmt->store_result();
                $username_stmt->bind_result($username);
                $username_stmt->fetch();
                $username_stmt->close();

                echo "

                    <div id='friend'>
                        <a href='profile.php?id=".$row['receiver_id']."'><img src='". getProfileImagePath($row['receiver_id'], $sqli_con) . "' /></a>
                        <a href='profile.php?id=".$row['receiver_id']."'>". $username . "</a>
                    </div>

                ";
            }
        }

    } else {
        $results->free();
        return "You don't have any friends yet! :( Why not search for some?";
    }
}
```

Not pretty but it'll do. Thanks for the help guys.(Tested with multiple entries and it works)

Comment: Please post your *relevant* code here, not only at an external source. That way, it will be preserved for future reference on SO.

Comment: I have been nice enough to post your image and relevant (just the one function) code here for you. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: He's just new here... It takes time. `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (receiver_id = '$user_id' OR sender_id = '$user_id') AND accepted = '1'`

Comment: Sorry about that, I couldn't get the code to be readable in the code markdown and images aren't allowed to be posted until I have 10 rep.

Comment: @LiamPotter Just so I'm clear, is that image after a query? Please tell me you don't only have 1 record in your table...

Comment: That image was before the query, the record hasn't changed since.

Comment: Yes that is the only entry in the table: user_id 19 is another user in my system and user_id 12 is the user I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You returned from within the loop. Try something like:

```
$result_string = '';
// the loop definition here
$result_string .= "<div id='friend'>
                        <a href='profile.php?id=".$id."'><img src='". getProfileImagePath($id, $sqli_con) . "' /></a>
                        <a href='profile.php?id=".$id."'>". $username . "</a>
                   </div>";
// closing the loop
return $result_string;
```

Comment: This still only returns the current user :/

Comment: @LiamPotter I think he meant, you need to append all records to it before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

Won't `$user_id` will always be present in the resulting record-set?

Instead of ignoring the records with `$user_id` you need to process them all from the result-set. Extracting the other ID in the record, other column gives you a friend ID!

Also, implement Lim's suggestion for multiple records in record set.

Comment: No.. If I am person 13 but person 16 has requested to be friends with person 21 the record would read `16, 21, 1`. Me (`$user_id`) being person 13, isn't in the record.

Comment: then 13 is not a friend of anyone if he doesn't have any records in the result-set. Isn't it?